# Find $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y\partial z}$

Tags: partial-derivative

if $z=x^3 -3xy^2 $
show that

$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial ^2z}{\partial y\partial z}$

I got $$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}=-6y$$

but have no idea how to find $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y\partial z}$
will appreciate if anyone can give any clue..

Comment: $\frac{\partial z^2}{\partial x\partial y}$ or $\frac{\partial^{\color{red}{2}} z}{\partial x\partial y}$ ?

Comment: $\frac{\partial^{\color{blue}{2}} z}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^{\color{blue}{2}} z}{\partial y\partial \color{red}{x}}$ and $\frac{\partial^{\color{blue}{2}} z}{\partial x\partial y}=\color{red}{-}6y$. Correct these & then think about your question again.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit  $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}$correction thanks..

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit no ,it's said to find  $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y\partial z}$

Comment: Are you sure ? $\frac{\partial z}{\partial z}=1$ so $\frac{\partial ^2z}{\partial y\partial z}=0$. I think the question wants you to show that it does not matter what order you perform the $x$ and $y$ derivatives.